# Adding custom projection to GDAL library?

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, epsg

Can i add my custom projection definition to GDAL library in CentOS?

For example, if i want to add custom projection def. in PostGIS i use simple SQL command for inserting projection. But i do not find how i add projection to GDAL library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDAL uses Proj.4 for projections, so you can edit the "epsg" (without extension) file to add a new projection.

Otherwise, you can specify a custom projection directly through the command line as described here
http://gdal.org/gdal_utilities.html
in section "-a_srs SRS"

Comment: Thanks, but i not find "epsg" (without extension), i find only directory /usr/share/epsg_csv/ where are some files for projection.